# UItextfield not editable when we tapped on it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield, uitableviewsectionheader

Hi i am very new for ios and in my app i have added UITableList and here i have added `UIView` `xib` file on `tableList` `HeaderView`

And here i have added one `UItextfield` on `UIView` `xib` file and when i click that `textfield` it's not editable i mean `click action not working` please help me some one

### my code:-

```
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    UIView *HeaderView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    HeaderView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    header = [[EscortHederView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(HeaderView.frame.origin.x, HeaderView.frame.origin.y, HeaderView.frame.size.width, HeaderView.frame.size.height)];
    [HeaderView addSubview:header];

    header.coridersTextfield.delegate = self;
    header.coridersTextfield.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    return HeaderView;
}
```

Comment: header.coridersTextfield.editable = YES;

Comment: how can i set can u post code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this in the following any one ways

```
header.coridersTextfield.editable = YES;
// or 

 header.coridersTextfield.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

// or 

  header.coridersTextfield. enabled = YES;
```

or using delegate method

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
return YES;
}
```

**Update**

```
UIView *HeaderView = [[UIView alloc] init];
HeaderView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y, width, height); // customize frame and set the Height based on your Subviews Height
```

Comment: check once your `header` userInteraction is enabled or not

Comment: @AbhiRam -- you foreget to allocate the frame of `HeaderView` , set the frame and try once, the reason you were added the all subviews to `HeaderView`

Comment: no no use still no use and can i send my sample x code file please see once it's small one

Comment: can you show your connection inspector of textfield

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103171/discussion-between-abhiram-and-anbu-karthik).

Answer (score 0):

The bounds of HeaderView is (x:0, y:0, width:0, height:0)

do following:

```
UIView *HeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGrectGetWidth(tableView.bounds), 44.0f)];
```

Answer (score -1):

Select the textView and check the property inspector. This might be the case!

[image]